# Parse error: Failed parsing args: missing field > account_id" on NEAR dApp

Tags: nearprotocol

I deployed the contract on another computer and it worked, and now on a new envirenment and account the NEAR dApp is failing; here is the code:

https://github.com/bobmakesmagics/Multi-Near-NFT-Minter

```
// Get blockchian state once on component load and wallet is connected:f
nft.nftSupply(wallet.accountId)
.then(setTotalSupply)
.catch(console)
```

> Error: [-32700] Parse error: Failed parsing args: missing field
> account_id"

before I make the RPC call I actually console.log the args.. and there you see the account_id not missing... so what's the problem?

[image: field account_id missing]

Comment: Since you mentioned it working on a different environment, have you checked that all of your environment variables are the same?

Comment: I mean why should that play a role? I just need someone who tests the contract on a different machine - build, deploy, start dapp to see if its working also on a different account. Since other examples on NEAR website work very well.. (the helloworld, the counter...)

Comment: @Suisse I'm unable to reproduce the issue, first thing I suggest is to upgrade your SDK version to latest (0.6.0 at the moment) https://github.com/near/near-sdk-js/releases

Comment: I tried to go through the steps in the GitHub repo provided, but I'm getting a different error, "Contract state empty", when I run the front-end